# How to add a UITableViewController to a UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I'm adding a UITableViewController's view to a UITableViewCell

StudentTableView is of type UITableViewController

```
StudentTableVC *childTableView = [StudentTableVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"StudentTableVC" bundle:nil];
childTableView.studentList =arrayList;
[cell.contentView addSubview:childTableView.view];
```

I can see the table inside cell but StudentTableVC table delegate and data source methods not called thats why i'm unable to see StudentTableVC cell content.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Cells go into tables, tables go in to table view controllers. Are you trying to have a table view in the cell itself, or do you want to have way to communicate between each cell and the view controller?

Comment: I'm trying to have a table in cell

Comment: I have create a separate UITableViewController that is StudentTableVC.and i'm try to add to a table cell , the issue is the StudentTableVC table delegate method not getting called.

Comment: Then you don't need a controller. Set the table's delegate and data source as the cell, and implement the needed methods there.

Answer (score 0):

```
StudentTableVC *childTableView = [StudentTableVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"StudentTableVC" bundle:nil];
childTableView.delegate = self;
childTableView.dataSource = self;
childTableView.studentList =arrayList;
[cell.contentView addSubview:childTableView.view];
```